# React-Native App doesn't install in IOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, simulator

Already tried those [React-Native App doesn't install in IOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160511/react-native-app-doesnt-install-in-ios-simulator?noredirect=1#)

I am trying to run react-native run-ios. Everytime I get the following error:

```
Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 
Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug- 
iphonesimulator/rnCourse.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:602:13)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:622:13)
at Promise.then (/Users/lucas/Documents/ReactC/rnCourse/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:208:5)
at <anonymous>
```

This is my current Info.plist

[image]

Comment: Not a duplicated. Already tried all those solutions

Comment: Make sure that all of your dependencies are added to the header search paths, and are listed in the `link binary with libraries` section

Comment: @LucasCouto, the error says "bundle identifier" doesn't exist. did you check if its available or not?

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from no developer account being associated with the project. You can fix this in Xcode by opening the project and assigning a team in the Signing section of the General tab.

[image]